# on check of Radio button change source from xml file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, datasource, xslt-2.0

I have 2 radio button name cube 1 and cube 2.And Beneath this radio button I am getting records in a specific column which I have listed.

My XML file are data.xml and data1.XML both of them are same but are called upon check of different radio button

Like if cube 1 radio button is selected it will choose data from data.XML file and when I click Cube 2 radio button it will choose the data from  Data1.xml file.

Right now i need to combine them..

Xslt file as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
          <xsl:template match="/">
            <html>
              <body style="font-family:Helvetica Neue">
                <Div id="ListingScreen">

                  <table border="1" width="1024px" >
                    <tr bgcolor="blue">

                      </FONT>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td align="right" colspan="10">


                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                      <td colspan="10">



                        <input id="cube1" type="radio" name="Cube" value="1" checked="true"> Cube1</input>
                        <input id="cube2" type="radio" name="Cube" value="2">Cube2</input>

                      </td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th id="location">Location ID</th>
                      <th>Data Entry</th>
                      <th>Export</th>
                      <th>Local View</th>
                      <th>Banner</th>
                      <th>Server</th>
                      <th>View</th>
                      <th>Locl</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="CATALOG/orderByTitle">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="CATALOG/CD">
                          <xsl:sort select="TITLE" />
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:when test="CATALOG/orderByTitleDesc">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="CATALOG/CD">
                          <xsl:sort select="TITLE" order="ascending" />
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:when test="CATALOG/orderByArtist">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="CATALOG/CD">
                          <xsl:sort select="ARTIST" />
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                      </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                  </table>
                </Div>
              </body>
            </html>
          </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="CD" >
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="ID" />
          </td>
                            <p style="display:none;">
                              <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
                            </p>
                            <xsl:value-of select="LocationID"/>
                          </a>
                </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="DataEntry" value="dataentry">
              <xsl:if test="DataEntry='Yes'">
                <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:if>
            </input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Export" value="export">
              <xsl:if test="Export='Yes'">
                <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:if>
            </input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="LocalView" value="localview">
              <xsl:if test="LocalView='Yes'">
                <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:if>
            </input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Banner"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Server"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="View"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Location01"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My xml file are as follows: which are in same format 1)Data.xml  2)Data1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<CATALOG>
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <CD>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <LocationID>Location</LocationID>
    <ChangeValueFor>Data per Subclass</ChangeValueFor>
    <Banner>Forecast is open</Banner>
    <DataEntry>Yes</DataEntry>
    <LocalView>Yes</LocalView>
    <Export>Yes</Export>
    <View>1</View>
    <ActiveView>Data</ActiveView>
    <HelpFile>Testfile</HelpFile>
    <Location01>1</Location01>
    <Location02>2</Location02>
    <Location03>3</Location03>
    <Location04>4</Location04>
    <Location05>5</Location05>
    <Location06>6</Location06>
    <Location07>7</Location07>
    <Location08>8</Location08>
    <Location09>9</Location09>
    <Location10>10</Location10>
    <Location11>11</Location11>
    <Location12>12</Location12>
    <Server>KLJJLK</Server>
    <Server2>Select</Server2>
    <Server3>Select</Server3>
    <CodeBase>HKJHJKK</CodeBase>
    <CodeBase2>NA</CodeBase2>
    <CodeBase3>NA</CodeBase3>
    <ClassiscID>KLJLKJLJ</ClassiscID>
    <ClassiscID2>NA</ClassiscID2>
    <ClassiscID3>NA</ClassiscID3>
    <Theme>Cubus</Theme>
    <Theme2>NA</Theme2>
    <Theme3>NA</Theme3>
    <Theme4>NA</Theme4>
    <Theme5>NA</Theme5>
    <Theme6>NA</Theme6>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

And the 2nd file which is Data1.xml looks the same with same tags just change of values.Now how do i call different data.xml or data1.xml on check of radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Can we assume you are running this transformation within the browser, invoked via Javascript API? (If not, please tell us how you are running it.)

One way of doing this is to use Saxon-JS, which allows a client-side stylesheet to handle user-input events directly, without Javascript coding. It would look something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="input" mode="ixsl:onclick">
  <ixsl:schedule-action document="{if (@name='DataEntry') 
                                   then 'data.xml' 
                                   else 'data1.xml'}">
    <xsl:call-template name="process-xml-file"/>
  </ixsl:schedule-action>
</xsl:template>
```

Once the XML document has been asynchronously fetched, it will then be processed (as the context item) by the named template `process-xml-file`, which can update selected parts of the HTML page using the `xsl:result-document` instruction.